# Selecting column names when configuring crawler

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

It is possible to define which columns are to be included in the table created by a crawler? I have a JSON file with over 20 columns but at the end I just need to use 2 columns. Where can I configure it?

Answer (score 0):

AWS Glue provides a possibility to use [custom classifiers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-classifier.html). Using [Grok patterns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/custom-classifier.html#custom-classifier-grok) you can configure it to select only those columns that you want.

For example, if your CSV looks like this:

```
1,20/08/2018,test,230
```

and you want to select second and last columns only then grok pattern should be following:

```
^[^\,]*\,%{DATE_EU:date}\,[^\,]*\,%{NUMBER:amount:int}$
```

You can test it in [this online tool](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result) before using in Glue.